# SimpleFlatMapper and jOOQ fails on JSON columns

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jooq

I am querying a table representing a file on a Posgress DB using the frameworks jOOQ and SFM. The table among others columns has and md5 checksum and a details columns whose type is JSONObject. I am using the POJOS generated by the jOOQ for setting the mapping.

I get an error when executing the following test case:

```
public void testSelectFile(){

    String md5 = "dfsg3456gfhg";

    JdbcMapper<File> jdbcMapper = JdbcMapperFactory.newInstance()
            .newMapper(File.class);

    Function<File, File> fileFileFunction = l -> l;
    try (DSLContext context = DSL.using(getDataSource(), SQLDialect.POSTGRES)) {
        try (ResultSet rs = context.selectFrom(FILE).where(FILE.MD5.eq(md5)).fetchResultSet()) {
             jdbcMapper.stream(rs)
                    .findAny()
                    .map(fileFileFunction::apply)
                    .orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
    }
}
```

The error obtained is this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.simpleflatmapper.util.TypeHelper.toClass(TypeHelper.java:29)
at org.simpleflatmapper.util.TypeHelper.toBoxedClass(TypeHelper.java:171)
at org.simpleflatmapper.util.TypeHelper.isAssignable(TypeHelper.java:144)
at org.simpleflatmapper.converter.ConverterService.findConverter(ConverterService.java:62)
at org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.meta.MapClassMeta.<init>(MapClassMeta.java:30)
at org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.ReflectionService.newMapMeta(ReflectionService.java:163)
at org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.ReflectionService.newClassMeta(ReflectionService.java:150)
at org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.ReflectionService.getClassMeta(ReflectionService.java:128)
at org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.meta.PropertyMeta.newPropertyClassMeta(PropertyMeta.java:53)
at org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.meta.PropertyMeta.getPropertyClassMeta(PropertyMeta.java:46)
at org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.meta.ObjectPropertyFinder.lookForSubProperty(ObjectPropertyFinder.java:113)
at org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.meta.ObjectPropertyFinder.lookForConstructor(ObjectPropertyFinder.java:66)
at org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.meta.ObjectPropertyFinder.lookForProperties(ObjectPropertyFinder.java:38)
at org.simpleflatmapper.reflect.meta.PropertyFinder.findProperty(PropertyFinder.java:28)
at org.simpleflatmapper.map.mapper.PropertyMappingsBuilder._addProperty(PropertyMappingsBuilder.java:95)
at org.simpleflatmapper.map.mapper.PropertyMappingsBuilder.addProperty(PropertyMappingsBuilder.java:73)
at org.simpleflatmapper.map.mapper.ConstantSourceMapperBuilder.addMapping(ConstantSourceMapperBuilder.java:109)
at org.simpleflatmapper.map.mapper.AbstractMapperBuilder.addMapping(AbstractMapperBuilder.java:171)
at org.simpleflatmapper.jdbc.JdbcMapperFactory$SetRowMapperFactory.newInstance(JdbcMapperFactory.java:310)
at org.simpleflatmapper.jdbc.JdbcMapperFactory$SetRowMapperFactory.newInstance(JdbcMapperFactory.java:298)
at org.simpleflatmapper.map.mapper.DynamicSetRowMapper.getMapper(DynamicSetRowMapper.java:101)
at org.simpleflatmapper.map.mapper.DynamicSetRowMapper.getMapperFromSet(DynamicSetRowMapper.java:91)
at org.simpleflatmapper.map.mapper.DynamicSetRowMapper.stream(DynamicSetRowMapper.java:74)
at org.simpleflatmapper.jdbc.JdbcMapperFactory$DynamicJdbcSetRowMapper.stream(JdbcMapperFactory.java:251)
```

The versions I am using are:

- org.jooq:jooq:3.10.4
- org.simpleflatmapper:sfm-jooq:3.13.4

I am wondering whether I am missing some configuration or whether I have to better define the mapper so not to fail on JSONObjet columns.

Any hint or comment is going to be much appreaciated.

**EDIT 1**
I've managed to work around the issue by choosing the columns I need to retrieve by not including the JSONObject one. For instance the following test case code work out:

```
public void testSelectFile(){

    String md5 = "dfsg3456gfhg";

    JdbcMapper<File> jdbcMapper = JdbcMapperFactory.newInstance()
        .newMapper(File.class);

    final List<Field<?>> columns = new ArrayList<Field<?>>();
    columns.add(FILE.ID);
    columns.add(FILE.FILENAME);

    Function<File, File> fileFileFunction = l -> l;
    try (DSLContext context = DSL.using(getDataSource(), SQLDialect.POSTGRES)) {
        try (ResultSet rs = context.select(columns).from(FILE).where(FILE.MD5.eq(md5)).fetchResultSet()) {
             jdbcMapper.stream(rs)
                .findAny()
                .map(fileFileFunction::apply)
                .orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
    }
}
```

It is worth to pint out that this is not going to fix the issue regarding JSONObject, it only provides a way to avoid the issue.

Comment: could you create a ticket here https://github.com/arnaudroger/SimpleFlatMapper/issues/new ? also have you tried with the last version 3.15.10? There has been quite a few fix related to type, even if it's not fix the error message will be more useful

Comment: looking at the code is seems to feel on building the meta data link to a Map class, and somehow end up with the keyType of the map being null. Could you copy the code of the File class or are you using the java one?

Comment: is the JSONObject the one from org.jooq.tools.json ? will try and reproduce.

Comment: created one https://github.com/arnaudroger/SimpleFlatMapper/issues/494 wish I could create a simpleflatmapper tag

Comment: could you try with sfm-jooq 3.5.11 I fixed the NPE and also added a converter from String to JSONObject, hopefully that should make it work. if not could you reopen the ticket?

Comment: @user3996996: it worked out, by the way the version is 3.15.11.

Comment: happy days, I've just seen that entry thanks to a retweet of the Json stackoverflow bot. don't hesitate to raise on issue next time!